# Proving combinatorical equality

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}2^k=3n, \quad n\in \mathbb{N}
> $$

(The exercise says $n\geq 0$ but then the base case is incorrect so I'm assuming it's a typo and should be $n>0$.)

It does not say how to prove this but we've been doing induction so I thought I might do that, even though I find it a bit tedious more often than not when dealing with factorials. I start by doing the base case:

> BASE CASE:
>
> $n=1 \Longrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^1{1 \choose k}2^k={1 \choose 0}1+{1 \choose 1}2=3 \Leftrightarrow 3*1=3$

Then, the inductive step.

> INDUCTIVE STEP:
>
> Assume that the equality holds for some $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}{n_0 \choose k}2^k=3n_0$.

What remains is to show that this implies
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n_0+1} {n_0+1 \choose k}2^k=3(n_0+1).
$$

I quite quickly get stuck, unfortunately. Here's what I've tried:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n_0+1} {n_0+1 \choose k}2^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n_0} {n_0+1 \choose k}2^k+2^{n_0+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}\frac{(n_0+1)n_0!}{(n_0+1-k)(n_0-k)!}2^k+2^{n_0+1}\\
=(n_0+1)\sum_{k=0}^{n_0}\frac{n_0!}{(n_0+1-k)(n_0-k)!}2^k+2^{n_0+1}
$$

What should I do next? Any hints?

Comment: There’s a horrible typo in the statement of the identity: the righthand side should be $3^n$. I suggest deleting the question and giving it another go with the correct identity.

Comment: Exactly right Brian! Hope someone can edit the question properly!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ugh, that would explain it. So I guess that was the typo in the formulation of the exercise rather than $n\geq 0$ as I thought... I tried deleting the post but I can't since it's been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}2^k=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}2^k1^{n-k}=(1+2)^n=3^n,   \quad n\in \mathbb{N}
$$

Comment: Oh jeez. That was a bit easier, wasn't it? :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combinatorial proof. The left hand side counts the subsets of an $n$-element set where each element is colored red or blue. But each colored subset can be obtained by doing one of three things to each element of the set: color it red, color it blue or leaving it out.